# Django inline model: can I apply a different css to the header?

Tags: css, django, model, header, inline

Django 2.2
I have inline mode which works fine as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33748059/add-inline-model-to-django-admin-site). Both main model and inline model are using default Django templates, nothing is custom yet.

I also have defined `verbose_name_plural` for it which shows as the header to the inline model table.

My question is: is there a way to apply a css class to the header text, something like this:

```
class SomeForeignKeyInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = SomeForeignKey
    verbose_name_plural = "My Header Text" #works
    css = "<some_css_class_I_want_to_apply_to_header_text>"
```

I did not find anything reading this: [Django docs on inline models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.verbose_name)

Thanks