# Adding new item to foreign key field when creating an item for which it is related

Tags: django, django-admin

I have two models `apartment` and `image` defined as

```py
class Apartment(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(...)
   price = models.DecimalField(...)

class Image(models.Model):
   apartment = models.ForeignKey(to="Apartment")
```

I have them set up this way so I can have Many Images to One Apartment `ManyToOne Rel`

Is there a way to add new Images when adding a new Apartment? There is no field for Images in the Apartment admin section of the Django Admin Panel

Comment: My question has been answered [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33748059/add-inline-model-to-django-admin-site)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have Inline for your Image model that you use it in your `ApartmentModelAdmin`. So your `admin.py` module should be like below code snippet:

```py
from django.contrib.admin import register, ModelAdmin
from your_app_name.models import Apartment, Image

class SleepInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model=Image

@register(Apartment)
class ApartmentModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (SleepInline, )
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add an image field to the `Image` model. Then you can save single or multiple images for an `Apartment` object